# How to get useful css property data using JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, properties

I'm currently working on a simple code to get the css property of a text that its style color attribute was set in an external css file. I want to use that color property to toggle between two colors. But, my problem is information that the css() returns it unusable to me.

> HTML

```
<h1 id="p">Zzzzz</h1>
<button type="button" id="button">click</button>
```

> CSS

```
h1{
  color:yellow;
}
```

> Javascript

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  let t = $('#p').css("color");
  console.log(t);

  //check returned color to toggle between two colors
  if(t != "red"){
    $('#p').css('color','red');
  }else if(t != 'yellow'){
    $('#p').css('color','yellow');
  }
  else{
    console.log("Dunno");  
  }
});
```

The value that the code :"let t = $('#p').css("color");" is "rgb(255,255,0)". which is good and all but I can't really use that in my if statement to check if I should toggle or not. What's a better way around this?

Comment: use a class or a data-* attribute to store and use states. don't use the color property unless you have to

Answer (score 0):

you could use the returned value as it is

```
if (t != 'rgb(255,255,0)') {
    $('#p').css('color','yellow');
} else if (t != 'rgb(255,0,0)') {
    $('#p').css('color','red');
} else {
    console.log("Dunno");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi, there!

It will be better to toggle based on another class, isn't it?

```js
$(function(){
  $('.toggle').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle--active');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: pink;
}
.toggle.toggle--active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">Click me to toggle.</div>
```